# How do you split a string of pipe separated values and return an array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(160)     "|ad|al|at|ax|ba|be|bg|by|ch|cz|de|dk|ee|es|eu|fi|fo|fr|gb|gg|gi|gr|hr|hu|ie|im|is|it|je|li|lt|lu|lv|mc|md|me|mk|mt|nl|no|pl|pt|ro|rs|ru|se|si|sj|sk|sm|tr|ua|va|"
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to strip the pipes and turn them each into an array.

Here's the code that will output the results.

```
<?php 
if( in_array( 'gb',     get_field('rights_management_control_by_continent_europe') ) or 'gb' ==     get_field('rights_management_control_by_continent') ) {
?>   

STUFF HERE

<?php } ?>
```

And just out of curiosity, is this doable in JavaScript?

Comment: Does `<insert string here>.split("|");` work?

Comment: and in PHP you use [explode](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PHP `explode` tag.

```
<?php
$arr = ["|ad|al|at|ax|ba|be|bg|by|ch|cz|de|dk|ee|es|eu|fi|fo|fr|gb|gg|gi|gr|hr|hu|ie|im|is|it|je|li|lt|lu|lv|mc|md|me|mk|mt|nl|no|pl|pt|ro|rs|ru|se|si|sj|sk|sm|tr|ua|va|"];
$pieces = explode("|", $arr[0]);
```

Each item separated by the pipe symbol would be a new item in the away, with ad being [1] as you start with a pipe.

[ and ] can start and close an array

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript you can split string to array by using

```
s = "a|b|c"
arr = s.split('|') 

//access your array
arr[0]
arr[1]
.....
```

Comment: Because his data contains a starting `|` (and perhaps sometime a ending one) you can add the following: `"|1|2|3|".replace(/(^\||\|$)/g,'').split("|")`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

So you have this array, I'll just put it in a variable `$old_array`:

```
$old_array = array(0=>"|ad|al|at|ax|ba|be|bg|by|ch|cz|de|dk|ee|es|eu|fi|fo|fr|gb|gg|gi|gr|hr|hu|ie|im|is|it|je|li|lt|lu|lv|mc|md|me|mk|mt|nl|no|pl|pt|ro|rs|ru|se|si|sj|sk|sm|tr|ua|va|");
```

To split the string on index 0 we use the [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the first element in the `$old_array` array:

```
$exploded_array = explode("|", $old_array[0]);
```

The variable `$exploded_array` will now hold an array with all the pairs of letters as separate elements:

```
["","ad","al","at","ax","ba","be",...]
```

---

In JavaScript it would look a little different but still similar:

```
var old_array = ["|ad|al|at|ax|ba|be|bg|by|ch|cz|de|dk|ee|es|eu|fi|fo|fr|gb|gg|gi|gr|hr|hu|ie|im|is|it|je|li|lt|lu|lv|mc|md|me|mk|mt|nl|no|pl|pt|ro|rs|ru|se|si|sj|sk|sm|tr|ua|va|"];

var split_array = old_array[0].split('|');
```

The `split_array` variable will contain all the pairs of letters as separate elements:

```
["","ad","al","at","ax","ba","be",...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.